# Additions to hard apple cider

Tags: cider

Just put 5 gallons of hard apple cider in a better bottle to ferment. I would like to add some cinnamon, is there a good time and do I have to do anything special when I add it.

Comment: how do you upvote and whatdoes it mean //

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an expert, but I made a mead not too long ago with a tremendous amount of cinnamon (stick form). I made the mistake of adding the cinnamon before the fermentation and had a lot of trouble getting it to start. An otherwise identical batch made at the same time had no trouble with the same yeast. While this wasn't a cider, after some reading I learned that cinnamon can inhibit fermentation, so it's often recommended to add it after fermentation. It sounds like this is better for the yeast and otherwise has no adverse effects.

That said, I also made a mead the year before with less cinnamon, but that was still added before fermentation, and it had no problems.

For reference, there is a journal article that had some helpful figures and info:
http://aem.asm.org/content/47/2/229.full.pdf+html

Comment: Interesting paper. Garlic oil seems to have the strongest inhibitory effect on yeast growth. I guess that Roasted Garlic Lager I was planning is a bad idea.